# Converting data type of values with same key in JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, casting

I have a JSON file with lots of keys with the same name and what I want to do is change the data type of values of the keys which has same name using Python. Eg:-

```
{ 'name': 'Tom'
  'nick': 'T'
  'class': '2'
 }
{ 'name': 'Ron'
  'nick': 'R'
  'class': '5'
 }
```

Now here in the `"class"` key there are the values `'2', '5'` which is a string. Can we change those to integer? If so how?

P.s - The question might seem stupid because I am really new to these things but please bear with me.

Comment: It's easy task to achieve, try it yourself first. And if you encounter problem, then update the question.

Comment: int() https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int  is the Python standard built-in function to convert a string into an integer value

Comment: @vishes_shell yeah I really need to develop the thought process, if there is anything you recommend for that it'll be very helpful.

Comment: @l0n3_w01f decompose task, and try to come up with a solution to each, if no success, google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see what the rest of your dictionary looks like but here's a simple example. 
Let's say that this is your JSON dictionary:

```
dic={1:{'name': 'Tom','nick': 'T','class': '2'},
     2:{'name': 'Ron','nick': 'R','class': '5'}}

dic[1]['class']=int(dic[1]['class'])
dic[2]['class']=int(dic[2]['class'])

dic
```

{1: {'class': 2, 'name': 'Tom', 'nick': 'T'},
 2: {'class': 5, 'name': 'Ron', 'nick': 'R'}}

```
type(dic[1]['class'])
```

int

Inside your JSON structure is there any keys for each of the two values inside the curly braces similar to `1:` and `2:` ? those are keys.

Comment: Okay there are no keys but yes they are separate dicts so I think I can use indexing and it is doable. Sorry for wasting time of you guys and thank you.

Comment: No apology necessary. You just have to keep fishing through the keys down the tree branches until you get to the value you want and alter it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too overkill but if you use pandas it will do this for you automatically:

```
import pandas as pd

jsonstring = '''[{ "name": "Tom","nick": "T","class": "2"},
{ "name": "Ron","nick": "R","class": "5"}]'''

pd.read_json(jsonstring).to_dict('r')
```

Returns:

```
[{'class': 2, 'name': 'Tom', 'nick': 'T'},
 {'class': 5, 'name': 'Ron', 'nick': 'R'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to pass an object_hook to customize field modification:

```
my_json_str = """[
{ "name": "Tom",
  "nick": "T",
  "class": "2"
 },
{ "name": "Ron",
  "nick": "R",
  "class": "5"
 }
]
"""


def convert_class_to_int(my_dict):
    my_dict['class'] = int(my_dict['class'])
    return my_dict


import json

result = json.loads(my_json_str, object_hook=convert_class_to_int)
print(result)

# [{'class': 2, 'nick': 'T', 'name': 'Tom'}, {'class': 5, 'nick': 'R', 'name': 'Ron'}]
```