# Reading CSV and outputting json. Need to set data types

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a project where I am reading CSV and outputting to json.

Here is some sample CSV:

```
firstName,lastName,email,age,gender
John,Doe,jdoe@emaildomain.com,50,male
Jane,Doe,jdoe@emaildomain.com,28,female
Bill,Smith,bsmith@emaildomain.com,49,male
Dick,Tracy,dtracy@emaildomain.com,18,male
Peter,Parker,pparker@emaildomain.com,26,male
Clark,Kent,ckent@emaildomain.com,17,male
Wonder,Woman,wwoman@emaildomain.com,44,female
John,James,jjames@emaildomain.com,17,male
Kat,Whoaman,kwhoamans@emaildomain.com,23,female
```

Everything is working as I had hoped in terms of the output, except I need certain values to be integers in the output, but they come out as strings (age for example). Is there a way to keep the code that I have mostly in tact, but output certain values as integers rather than strings?

```py
import json
import csv
import itertools


primary_field = ['email']
result = []
with open('SampleCSV.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in itertools.islice(reader, 5):
        d = {k: v for k, v in row.items() if k in primary_field}
        d['dataFields'] = [{k: v,} for k, v in row.items() if k not in primary_field]
        result.append(d)

root = {}
root["users"] = result
print(json.dumps(root, indent=4))
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "email": "jdoe@emaildomain.com",
            "dataFields": [
                {
                    "firstName": "John"
                },
                {
                    "lastName": "Doe"
                },
                {
                    "age": "50"
                },
                {
                    "gender": "male"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "email": "jdoe@emaildomain.com",
            "dataFields": [
                {
                    "firstName": "John"
                },
                {
                    "lastName": "Doe"
                },
                {
                    "age": 50
                },
                {
                    "gender": "male"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I was just reviewing this question and can't help but throw a suggestion to you. Do a try-except on turning the field into an integer, int(). If it works, use the resultant variable. If not, then stick to the string.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47767719/6352720

Comment: @Spinor8 I am admittedly a n00b to this. Would I be doing the try-except in the for loop against row, or against the variable v? Or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I referred to earlier. The commented-out line is your original code.

```
import json
import csv
import itertools

primary_field = ['email']
result = []
with open('SampleCSV.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in itertools.islice(reader, 5):
        d = {k: v for k, v in row.items() if k in primary_field}
        # d['dataFields'] = [{k: v,} for k, v in row.items() if k not in primary_field]
        tmp_list = []
        for k,v  in row.items():
            if k not in primary_field:
                try:
                    vint = int(v)
                except ValueError:
                    vint = v
                tmp_list.append({k: vint})
        d['dataFields'] = tmp_list
        result.append(d)

root = {}
root["users"] = result
print(json.dumps(root, indent=4))
```

giving the results

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "email": "jdoe@emaildomain.com",
        "dataFields": [
            {
                "firstName": "John"
            },
            {
                "lastName": "Doe"
            },
            {
                "age": 50
            },
            {
                "gender": "male"
            }
        ]
    }, ...
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when I try to run it:

tmp_list = []
                ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Well, it should be indented to the same level as the commented out line. If it helps I can repost it with all your original code.

Comment: Hmmm, it definitely is. the line above the commented line should still exist:
`code`
        d = {k: v for k, v in row.items() if k in primary_field}

Correct?

Comment: Full code works, thanks so much. Strange as it was exactly as I had it, but I replaced with what you posted and all is well. Thanks again!